# Удалить класс у элемента при добавлении класса другому элементу на чистом JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем доброго времени суток. Такой вопрос, при клике на элемент, этому элементу добавляется класс _active, а у другого элемента класс _active должен удалиться. Еще только учу JavaScript, поэтому не особо понимаю что нужно сделать.

https://jsfiddle.net/yx5z4dfo/7/

```js
let circle_1 = document.querySelector('.circle-1');
let circle_2 = document.querySelector(".circle-2");
let circle_3 = document.querySelector(".circle-3");

let circleClickOne = document.querySelector('.block-circle-1');
let circleClickTwo = document.querySelector(".block-circle-2");
let circleClickThree = document.querySelector(".block-circle-3");

circle_1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  circleClickOne.classList.toggle("_active");
});

circle_2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  circleClickTwo.classList.toggle("_active");
});

circle_3.addEventListener('click', function() {
  circleClickThree.classList.toggle("_active");
});
```

```css
.circle-1 {
  color: red;
}

.circle-2 {
  color: red;
}

.circle-3 {
  color: red;
}

.block-circle-1 {
  display: none;
}

.block-circle-1._active {
  display: block;
}

.block-circle-2 {
  display: none;
}

.block-circle-2._active {
  display: block;
}

.block-circle-3 {
  display: none;
}

.block-circle-3._active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-1">Текст</div>
<div class="circle-2">Текст</div>
<div class="circle-3">Текст</div>

<div class="block-circle-1">Текст</div>
<div class="block-circle-2">Текст</div>
<div class="block-circle-3">Текст</div>
```

Comment: `if (p=document.querySelector("._active")) p.classList.toggle("_active");`

Comment: а куда это нужно вставить?

Comment: Перед каждой строкой с переключением класса, т.е. перед `circleClickOne.classList.toggle("_active");`, `circleClickTwo.classList.toggle("_active");`, и `circleClickThree.classList.toggle("_active");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так..... https://jsfiddle.net/5kx738wz/

1. Не надо привязывать addEvenListener к каждой кнопки, все наследники получают listener тоже
2. Манипуляции с querySelectorAll дают нужный результат, остаётся группировать ненужные и удалять, и манипулировать единым целым.
3. Одно из основных правил программирования, **не создавай копий кода**.

```html
<div id="circle_container">
  <div data-id="1">Текст</div>
  <div data-id="2">Текст</div>
  <div data-id="3">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="block-circle block-circle-1">Текст 1</div>
<div class="block-circle block-circle-2">Текст 2</div>
<div class="block-circle block-circle-3">Текст 3</div>
```

```js
function toggle($event) {
  сonst id = $event.target.dataset.id;
  if (!id) return; // container clicked!
  const el = document.querySelectorAll(".block-circle");
  [...el].forEach(e => e.classList.remove("_active"));
  document.querySelector(`.block-circle-${id}`).classList.add("_active");
}

document.getElementById("circle_container").addEventListener("click", $event => toggle($event));
```

```css
#circle_container > div {
  color:red;
}

.block-circle {
  display: none;
}

.block-circle._active {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сильно вашу функцию не переделывал, чтоб вам понятнее было.
Если вкратце, то перед навешиваем класса `_active` новому элементу, надо бы проходить по всем этим элементам и убирать уже существующие классы `_active`.

```js
let circle_1 = document.querySelector('.circle-1');
let circle_2 = document.querySelector(".circle-2");
let circle_3 = document.querySelector(".circle-3");

let circleClickOne = document.querySelector('.block-circle-1');
let circleClickTwo = document.querySelector(".block-circle-2");
let circleClickThree = document.querySelector(".block-circle-3");


function removeActiveClass() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.block').forEach((block) => block.classList.remove('_active'));
}

circle_1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  removeActiveClass();
  circleClickOne.classList.add("_active");
});

circle_2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  removeActiveClass();
  circleClickTwo.classList.add("_active");
});

circle_3.addEventListener('click', function() {
  removeActiveClass();
  circleClickThree.classList.add("_active");
});
```

```css
.circle-1 {
  color: red;
}

.circle-2 {
  color: red;
}

.circle-3 {
  color: red;
}

.block-circle-1 {
  display: none;
}

.block-circle-1._active {
  display: block;
}

.block-circle-2 {
  display: none;
}

.block-circle-2._active {
  display: block;
}

.block-circle-3 {
  display: none;
}

.block-circle-3._active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-1">Текст1</div>
<div class="circle-2">Текст2</div>
<div class="circle-3">Текст3</div>

<div class="block block-circle-1">Текст11</div>
<div class="block block-circle-2">Текст22</div>
<div class="block block-circle-3">Текст33</div>
```